# Query Redis geospatial data with a bounding box?

Tags: redis, geo, bounding-box

**I am trying to find a way to query geospatial data in Redis with a Bounding Box.**

After going through all the documentation on Redis's site the only reference to a bounding box I can find is in the [GEORADIUS](https://redis.io/commands/georadius) command's documentation;

> Time complexity: O(N+log(M)) where N is the number of elements inside the bounding box of the circular area delimited by center and radius and M is the number of items inside the index.

In other words, it seems like there is already a fundamental bounding box inside Redis, but for some reason it does not appear to be readily available to the user. I find this strange.

I am aware that there are some libraries available, such as [geo.lua](https://github.com/RedisLabs/geo.lua) which increases the capabilities of Redis. I would like to avoid extensions to my Redis database if possible, specially since it appears that the concept of a bounding box is already in the geospatial system for Redis.

I keep seeing references to a bounding box everywhere (eg. [Redis release notes](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/00-RELEASENOTES)) Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regrettably your research is correct - a bounding box query on a geoset is presently not available in core Redis.

That being the case, your alternative is to perform a radius search that includes the box, and then filter out results that fall outside the box. Filtering can be done:

- in the client: least efficient but probably easiest
- server-side Lua: similar to how geo.lua proposes
- server-side module: probably the most performant (and of possible use for the community) but also less trivial to implement

You may also submit a feature request to the Redis repository asking for this functionality to be part of the core and describing the use case - IMO it would be a nice addition.